# Silverlight on-demand compilation/Build

Tags: silverlight, deployment, msbuild, build

Is it possible to build silverlight application in on-demand manner. I have lot of silverlight applications to be shipped. I would like to ship the project files alone. Based on some user interaction, I would like to generate the XAP.

Comment: Are you sure you need to be building a Xap?  Do you really have the need to compile code dynamically?  If so how unique is that code?

Comment: It's like samples I want to ship. Previously, I was shipping pre-built sample along with xap. But, number of sample count grew very large. So, I want to compile them, when a specific action occurs. So, I can reduce my setup size. I won't be able to let the user to compile the project sample due to some restriction policy. So, the best case so far I think of is on-demand creation of XAP. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thought about using a NANT script to compile your project and grab the output xap file?